# Hooks not setting the state in REACT

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jasmine, react-hooks

In the following code, the hook shown below does not change the state of the variable newName.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

const App = () => {
    const [ persons, setPersons] = useState([
        { name: 'Arto Hellas' }
    ])
    const [ newName, setNewName ] = useState('')

    const textChangeHandler = (event)=>{
        event.preventDefault()
        setNewName(event.target.value) // WORKS FINE
    }

    const submitHandler = (event)=>{
        event.preventDefault()

        let temp = {name:newName}
        setNewName('')    //////////////////////////////////////// PROBLEM - doesnot set state!!
        console.log('tenp name is',temp.name)
        console.log('new name is',newName)
        setInterval(()=>console.log("Set Interval",newName), 1000)
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <h2>Phonebook</h2>
            <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
                <div>
                    name: <input onChange={textChangeHandler}  />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button type="submit" >add</button>
                </div>
            </form>
            <h2>Numbers</h2>
            {persons.map((person) => <Person key = {person.name} name={person.name}/> )}
        </div>
    )
}

const Person  = ({name})=> <p> {name} </p>
```

`setNewName` works fine and the name is updated when anything is typed in the input box. However, when I submit button, the `setNewName` does not seem to work. Even after updating, executing the `setNewName` the name is still the old name. 
I have even tried a setInterval (thinking it may be due to asynchronous nature of JS) and printed the newName but, it still shows the old name.

**What is the problem and how can it be fixed?**

thanks

Comment: Note that `setNewName` will only have effect after the next call to `render`

Comment: Can you use an `useEffect` hook to check if the value of state has changed , instead of `setInterval`?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at your `submitHandler` function, you will notice that the name its self has not changed... it remains empty as in its initial state. React only reload if the state value changes as shown below

```
const submitHandler = (event)=>{
        event.preventDefault()

        let temp = {name:newName}
        //setNewName('')    // your value is not changing here ... removing line
        setNewName(temp.name) // changing the name here with the one in temp
        console.log('tenp name is',temp.name)
        console.log('new name is',newName)
        setInterval(()=>console.log("Set Interval",newName), 1000)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As you know setting a state is asynchronous. **Never use scheduling functions like `setTimeout` `setInterval` to log out the value of state.**

Use `useEffect` instead -

```
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("value is", newName);
  }, [newName]);
```

You hook is working fine without a problem. Here's a [codeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/spring-monad-q7i9f) showing everything's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

In React setState is not synchronous ( with class components and hooks ).
So you can not expect that a new state will be available immediately.
You need to change the implementation of the submitHandler function.